# Task.Run blocking GUI, but inserting Thread.Sleep(1) frees it?

Tags: c#

I threw this together to try and figure out why my GUI is being blocked when there is a lot of data to be updated. I know Task.Run takes a lot of resources, but initially I only had one defined, and it still blocked. What is puzzling is why inserting Thread.Sleep(1) frees the GUI.
Also I am sure there must be a better way to do this kind of thing. I have a large number of GUI elements in main thread to update as the code runs, and it seems to be too much for this, or I am off track. Thoughts?

The example below is just a bunch of text boxes in a GUI, with one label and a button. The last textbox(8) is multi line. You can see I didn't spend much time trying to crunch this code down. ;)

````
```

public partial class MainWindow : Form
{
    private string _textBox1;
    private string _textBox2;
    private string _textBox3;
    private string _textBox4;
    private string _textBox5;
    private string _textBox6;
    private string _textBox7;
    private string _textBox8;
    private string _label1;
    
    private readonly SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext;
    
    List<string> aListString = new List<string>();
    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    }
    
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        var count = 0;
    
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (var i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
            {               
                aListString.Add(i.ToString());
    
                _label1 = (@"Counter " + count);
                UpdateLabel1(_label1);
                _textBox1 = (@"Counter " + count);
                UpdateTextBox1(_textBox1);
                _textBox2 = (@"Counter " + count);
                UpdateTextBox2(_textBox2);
                _textBox3 = (@"Counter " + count);
                UpdateTextBox3(_textBox3);
                _textBox4 = (@"Counter " + count);
                UpdateTextBox4(_textBox4);
                _textBox5 = (@"Counter " + count);
                UpdateTextBox5(_textBox5);
                _textBox6 = (@"Counter " + count);
                UpdateTextBox6(_textBox6);
                _textBox7 = (@"Counter " + count);
                UpdateTextBox7(_textBox7);
                //Thread.Sleep(1);
                _textBox8 = "\r\n" + aListString.Count.ToString();
                UpdateTextBox8(_textBox8);
    
                count = i;
            }
        });
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
    
    private async void UpdateLabel1(string aString)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => { synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o => { label1.Text = @"Counter " + (string)o; }), aString); });
    }
    
    private async void UpdateTextBox1(string aString)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => { synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o => { textBox1.Text = @"Counter " + (string)o; }), aString); });
    }
    
    private async void UpdateTextBox2(string aString)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => { synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o => { textBox2.Text = @"Counter " + (string)o; }), aString); }); 
    }
    
    private async void UpdateTextBox3(string aString)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => { synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o => { textBox3.Text = @"Counter " + (string)o; }), aString); }); 
    }
    
    private async void UpdateTextBox4(string aString)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => { synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o => { textBox4.Text = @"Counter " + (string)o; }), aString); }); 
    }
    
    private async void UpdateTextBox5(string aString)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => { synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o => { textBox5.Text = @"Counter " + (string)o; }), aString); });
    }
    
    private async void UpdateTextBox6(string aString)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => { synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o => { textBox6.Text = @"Counter " + (string)o; }), aString); });
    }
    
    private async void UpdateTextBox7(string aString)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => { synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o => { textBox7.Text = @"Counter " + (string)o; }), aString); });
    }
    
    private async void UpdateTextBox8(string aString)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => { synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o => { textBox8.Text += @"Counter " + (string)o; }), aString); });
    }
}

```
````

Comment: This code can't be optimized as it doesn't make much sense. You have HUGE overhead by using Task.Run and synchronizationContext.Post. The UI thread gets flooded with requests. The whole thing would probably run orders of magnitude faster without Tasks and Posts. The UI would get also blocked but for far less time.

Comment: I can't get your code to exhibit the behaviours you describe. Both with and without the Thread.Sleep(1) I sometimes get a random value in the textboxes until the UI thread eventually settles down on the final value. But this is expected based on the race condition you have with the shared String fields.

Comment: So your saying you can move the window around while the program is running? Did you try a longer duration? Thanks for looking at it. Could this be an issue with older computer hardware? My CPU is quad core, that should be enough right?